# Play the Guitar Amp within Garageband (Mac and iOS versions)

Tags: garageband, ios

Garageband has a cool Guitar Amp simulator, but as far as I can tell, you have to either:

1. Connect a physical electric guitar to your Mac or iOS.
2. On iOS you can use another app to be the source (Inter-App Audio).

Is there a way to have Garageband's own electric guitar sound be the input source to the Guitar Amp, so that no external instruments or apps are needed?